# Threads in parallel

Tags: c#, multithreading

The user user will write racing thread followed by file name at a command prompt:

`>>racing thread “file.txt”`

The program will create three threads, each thread will write numbers from 1 to 100 for 100 iteration in the specified file in step. The three threads must run at the same time.
this is my code but only one thread from the three that works and not in a parallel way.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace operating_system
{
    class Program
    {
        static Thread
            racing_th, 
            thread1,
            thread2,
            thread3;
        static string[] test;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter your commands " + "\n" + "To began press Enter ");
            string take;
            take = Console.ReadLine();
            do
            {
                /////////new\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
                if (test[0] == "racingthread")
                {
                    racing_th = new Thread(() => racingthread());
                    racing_th.Start();
                }
                Console.Write(">>");
                take = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            while (!take.Equals("close"));
        }

        static void writing()
        {
           try
           {
              int n = 0;
              // var tasks = n Task<int>[n];
              FileStream fs = new FileStream(test[1], FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
              StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
              for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
              {
                  sw.Write("\n"+i);
              }
              sw.Close();
              fs.Close();
           }
           catch (Exception exp){}
        }

        static  void racingthread()
        {
            //string[] ;
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(test[1], FileMode.Create);
            thread1 = new Thread(() => writing());
            thread1.Start(); 

            thread2 = new Thread(() => writing());
            thread2.Start(); 

            thread3 = new Thread(() => writing());
            thread3.Start(); 

            fs.Close();
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: test[0] == "racingthread" can never be true, because you neve assign any values to test[], so your never start the racingthread methode

Comment: @Turbofant i did not understand can you explain it agin

Comment: You never assign any value to the variable test in your code. So if(test[0] == "racingthread") in the Main method is never true.

Answer (score 1):

The solution you have provided seems overly verbose.  Why not use tasks and control it in a more simplistic way?

```
        Console.Write("Enter your commands \nPress any key to begin");
        Console.ReadKey();

        var task1 = new Task(() => { /* your action 1 here */ });
        var task2 = new Task(() => { /* your action 2 here */ });
        var task3 = new Task(() => { /* your action 3 here */ });

        // kick all tasks off at the same time
        task1.Start();
        task2.Start();
        task3.Start();

        // wait for all to finish
        Task.WaitAll(task1, task2, task3);

        // exit on keypress
        Console.Write("Press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: what is menat by{ /* your action 1 here */ } and where can i put my loop ?

Comment: You can put your code (the 'stuff' that is supposed to happen on each thread) in side those parentheses.  Which loop do you mean?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)

Comment: You can put that into each of the three tasks action sections ... do you really need to have a parent thread to spawn these three other threads?